# Interacting with Deployed contract- Truffle develop

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, truffle, truffle-contract

Hoping some of you may be able to help me. I have a very simple contract that i have deployed. I won't post the entire contract here, but i will post the one function i am having trouble calling from the terminal.

3 important things... I am using Truffle develop and connected to the network, i have already successfully gotten an instance of contract and I was able to call the other functions in the terminal. This withdrw function i am unable to call. Since it takes a uint I am simply putting in uint but when i call the function it doesn't work. instance.withdraw(22);  Shouldn't this call the function or do i need to put it in ether or something?

```
function withdraw(uint withdrawAmount) public returns (uint) {
        require(balances[msg.sender]>= withdrawAmount);
        balances[msg.sender] -= withdrawAmount;
        emit LogWithdrawal(msg.sender,
        withdrawAmount,balances[msg.sender]);
        return balances[msg.sender];
        }
}
```

Again just to be clear, i am looking for the command in the truffle develop terminal to call this function. I am using instance.withdraw(22); which is not working.

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure that you have defined the instance of the contract correctly. Then try to use async/await correctly in your orders in terminal. Finally, give this page a read :
"https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts"